How to Create a Custom Action in Fail2Ban to Execute a Bash File for Printing a Banner
I'm using Fail2Ban to enhance the security of my server by automatically banning IP addresses that attempt to log in unsuccessfully multiple times. I'd like to go further by displaying a custom banner message when Fail2Ban detects such incidents.
I've created a Bash script file containing the banner message I want to display, and I'm now looking to configure Fail2Ban to execute this script whenever a failed login attempt occurs. However, I'm unsure of the correct approach to achieve this.
Could someone please guide me through the steps to create a custom action in Fail2Ban that executes a Bash file for printing a banner upon failed login attempts? or give me any other way to achive it. I'm open for other idea's.
Here's what I've tried so far:
In my jail.conf file I've added:
[sshd]
...
action = %(action_)s
         /bin/bash /etc/fail2ban/banner.sh
         %(action_mw)s```


Printing banner where?

displayed in the terminal of the user attempting to log in.

Forget it. It's not an user; it's a automated process. You can tell sshd to send a banner, but not after failed attempts afaik, and not per IP.

I think if fail2ban can execute an iptable rule after a failed attempt which is a command in the first place. then I can too.

Does this answer your question? Custom error message for sshd - in short openssh doesn't support what you're looking for.

@princeroyce fail2ban creates an iptable rule and logs the action. If the logs report that your have multiple attempts to log into guest@yourserver.example.com that are coming form 172.16.1.1, I do wonder who you are going to send the email to? An ssh banner will not work since the banned IP cannot make a connection to sssd.

fail2ban works by installing an iptables rule (or nftables or firewalld) blocking the offending foreign address from access a particular port. Once this block is in place, the foreign IP will not be able to connect to your server. Without a connection, your server will not be able to return a banner.
The action parameter is to tell you, as the server admin, what is going on or to force the local server to take other evasive actions. It cannot communicate with the entity abusing your service.
